# Copying of type struct memory[] memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

How do I add a new empty Parent instance to the list of parents in the code sample below? I keep getting

```
UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Test.Child memory[] memory
to storage not yet supported.
```

Minimal example:

```
contract Test {
  struct Child { } 
  struct Parent { Child[] children; }

  Parent[] parents;

  function test() {
    parents.push(Parent(new Child[](0)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't really do what you're trying to do with dynamic arrays. You'll need to change your approach slightly to get it to work.

```
contract Test {
  struct Child { } 
  struct Parent { 
      mapping(uint => Child) children;
      uint childrenSize;
  }

  Parent[] parents;

  function testWithEmptyChildren() public {
      parents.push(Parent({childrenSize: 0}));
  }

  function testWithChild(uint index) public {
      Parent storage p = parents[index];

      p.children[p.childrenSize] = Child();
      p.childrenSize++;
  }
}
```

Use `Parent.childrenSize` if you need to iterate through `Parent.children` somewhere else in your contract.

Alternatively, you can increase the size of the `parents` array and use Solidity's default zero values.

```
contract Test {
  struct Child { } 
  struct Parent { Child[] children; }

  Parent[] parents;

  function test() public {
      parents.length++;
      Parent storage p = parents[parents.length - 1];

      Child memory c;

      p.children.push(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So you're saying that arrays can't be used that way and you'll have to use mappings as a workaround?

Comment: For this specific example, yes. The issue is you're trying to create what is essentially an empty `Parent` that has non-optional members. This could be the result of you providing a minimal example, but the approach is a bit weird because typically you wouldn't attempt to create an empty `Parent` like this. You would just increase the size of the array and Solidity automatically sets values to "zero". I'll edit the answer to include that last point.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn’t work (as of Solidity 0.4.24, at least) if the child array type is another struct, but it works if the child array type is a primitive type like `uint256`.

So if you have e.g.

```
struct Child {
  uint256 x;
  bytes32 y;
}
```

then you could define:

```
struct Parent {
  uint256[] childXs;
  bytes32[] childYs;
}
```

and then you could write:

```
parents.push(Parent({
    childXs: new uint256[](0),
    childYs: new bytes32[](0)
}));
```

(Same workaround is applicable when you want to pass an array of structs as an argument to  a public function.)

It’s not ideal, but it works.

P.S. Actually (if you are using the primitive array children) you could just write:

```
Parent memory p;
parents.push(p);
```