# Solidity change data location from memory to storage

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

Hi I have this code and the error is :

```
UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct spu_university.all_courses memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
```

How I can solve this ??

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract spu_university {

```
address  is_admin;
constructor(){
    is_admin = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyAdmin(address x) {
    require(x== is_admin, "Permission Denied. You do not have admin access.");
    _;  }

uint s_counter=0;

struct students_marks{
    uint id;
    uint mark;
}

struct  all_courses{

    string course_name ;
    uint mark ;
}

struct warning {

    string date ;
    string description;
}

struct  course {
    string name ;
    uint id;
    uint weekly_hours;
    uint level ;

    
    students_marks[] marks;
    }

    struct prof {
    
    uint id ;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string fatherName;
    string motherName;
    string gender;
    string email;
    string collegeName;
    string dateOfBirth;
    string mobileNumber; 
    string specialization ;


}

struct  student  {

    uint  id ;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string fatherName;
    string motherName;
    string gender;
    string email;
    string collegeName;
    string dateOfBirth;
    string mobileNumber;
    
    all_courses[] course;
    
    warning[] s_warnings;
    
    }

student[] studentList ;
prof[] profList;
course[] courselist; 

mapping(uint => student) public getstudent;
mapping(uint => prof) public getprof;   
mapping(uint => course) public getcours;
```

//---------------------------------- registrations functions  -------------------------------------------------------

```
function registerStudent(
    uint  _id,
    string memory _firstName,
    string memory _lastName,
    string memory _fatherName,
    string memory _motherName,
    string memory _gender,
    string memory _email,
    string memory _collegeName,
    string memory _dateOfBirth,
    string memory _mobileNumber

    ) onlyAdmin(msg.sender) public {

    
          student memory x= student(_id,_firstName,
          _lastName,_fatherName,_motherName,_gender,
          _email,_collegeName,_dateOfBirth,
          _mobileNumber,
          new all_courses[] (0),
          new warning[] (0) );
          
          studentList.push(x);

    getstudent[_id]=studentList[s_counter];
    s_counter ++;
    
}
```

}

I tried a lot of things did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a storage - memory mismatch here. I wont go into detail what storage and memory is about, you can read about it here [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/data-locations/).

Also, you find other stackoverflow posts about similar problems to yours which explain why this specific error occurs, for example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345903/copying-of-type-struct-memory-memory-to-storage-not-yet-supported) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117658/copying-of-type-struct-memory-memory-to-storage-not-yet-supported).

However, I will give you some starting point on how to restructure your code, so you do not run into the same error again. Have a look at the following more simplified example derived from yours.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;


contract spu_university {
    constructor(){
    }

    uint s_counter=0;

    struct course {
        string name;
    }

    struct student {
        uint  id;
        string firstName;
        course[] all_courses;
    }


    mapping(uint => student) public getstudent;
    
    function registerStudent(
        uint  _id,
        string memory _firstName
        ) public {
            student storage s = getstudent[_id];

            s.id = _id;
            s.firstName = _firstName;

            course memory c;
            c.name = "some course name";
            s.all_courses.push(c);

            s_counter ++; 
    }

    function addCourseToStudent(uint  _id) public {
        student storage s = getstudent[_id];

        course memory c;
        c.name = "some other course name";

        s.all_courses.push(c);
    }

    function getCourseOfStudent(uint _id) public view returns (course[] memory) {
        return getstudent[_id].all_courses;
    }
}
```