# I need to store dynamic array of struct type in another struct in Solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, dynamic-arrays, remix

`struct ProductQuantity{ string product;                 //MUDAR PARA PRODUCT uint128 quantity; string unity; string originMachine;       //MUDAR PARA MACHINE } struct Movement{ string originMachine;       //mudar para MACHINE string destinationMachine;  //mudar para MACHINE string responsibleWorker; //mudar para WORKER ou ids ProductQuantity[] product; }`

I have the following structs.
When I want to register a new movement, I try this:

```
 function registerMovement (string memory originMachine, string memory destinyMachine, string memory newWorker, ProductQuantity[] memory products) public {
    

    Movement memory newMovement = Movement({
        originMachine: originMachine,
        destinationMachine: destinyMachine,
        responsibleWorker: newWorker,
        product: products
    });

    movements.push(newMovement);
}
```

I get the following error that won't make the program compile:
UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct ProductQuantity memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.

How can I work this around? Using Solidity 0.8.19 in Remix IDE

I need to have this in array, but can't figure out a way.

Comment: You should consider using a mapping instead of an array. Have a look at an answer of a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76183520/solidity-change-data-location-from-memory-to-storage/76189827#76189827).

Comment: @norym I tried to use a mapping, but the problem persists. I can't copy from memory (from the argument received) directly to the Movement's products, how do I do it?

Comment: could u post more code, so i can test it in remix